# Pass arguments to an object when using Prototype Pattern

Tags: javascript

I have this function Person, and an object where I define name, age and job. But I wonder if it is possible to make the properties name, age and job not to be static values. Can I somehow pass in values via the new Person()?

I have tried it, but can't get it really to work, but maybe it is not possible?

```
function Person() { }

Person.prototype = {
   name: 'Tony Stark',
   age: 48,
   job: 'Iron Man',
   sayName: function() {
      console.log(this.name);
   }
}
var person1 = new Person();
person1.sayName();
```

Comment: Do you mean `function Person(name, age, job) { this.name = name; this.age = age; this.job = job; }` and `Person.prototype.sayName = function() { console.log(this.name); }` ?

Comment: you can just manually add `person.name = "John"` or whatever. But it's more usual to set these with arguments in the "contructor", as @YeldarKurmangaliyev says.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Ok, so I need to set this.name etc in the function, I'm not able to set them in the Person.prototype?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the default values, you should use an explicit comparison with undefined.

Something like this:

```
function Person(name, age, job) {
  if(name|| name=== 0)this.name= name;
  if(age|| age=== 0)this.age= age;
  if(job|| job=== 0)this.job= job;
}

Person.prototype.name= 'Tony Stark';
Person.prototype.age= 48;
Person.prototype.job= 'Iron Man';

var person = new Person();

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way,

```js
function Person(name,age){
   this.name=name;this.age=age;
}
var p = new Person("s",34);
console.log(p.name) // prints "s" on console
console.log(p.age) // prints 34 on console
```